# Function pointer in function argument

Tags: c, function

I have following function

```
unsigned char foo(unsigned char(*fun[])(unsigned char *))
```

How to pass an argument to this function?

Comment: Just pass a function name of the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

That function prototype declare a function that takes as parameter an arraay of functions pointer. Each function pointer must have type `unsigned char function_name(unsigned char *)`

For example you can do: (changed passed pars to ease the example)

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char dummy(char *dummypar)
{

    printf("Dummy: %s\n", dummypar);

    return 0;
}

unsigned char dummy2(char *dummypar)
{
    printf("Dummy2: %s\n", dummypar);

    return 0;
}

unsigned char foo(unsigned char(*fun[])(char *))
{
    char *test = "test";
    size_t i = 0;

    while (fun[i] != NULL)
    {
        fun[i](test);

        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}

unsigned char(*array[])(char *) = { dummy, dummy2, NULL };

int main ( void )
{
    foo(array);
}
```